# HTML Prevent part of text from going to next line

Tags: html

I am displaying long text on a web page and I am using the paragraph tag to separate my sentences. However, when my first set of text shows half of the sentence shows on the next line.

```
<p>This is some random text that I am typing on the screen for an example. </p>
<p>My second line for this example </p>
```

Here is what shows on the screen:

```
This is some random text that I am
typing on the screen for
an example.
My second line for this example
```

For this case, "an example" should be on the second line but it's not.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If it goes to the next line, there's not enough room on the current one. Try widening the area. You should show a live example with your css to get more detailed advice.

Comment: Consider changing the width of the paragraph tags, or better yet, create a parent envelope to handle it.

Comment: Such things don’t happen. In the example, the word “an” would appear on the second line. The code posted does *not* produce the problem described. Please provide complete code that actually demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep all content of 'p' inside in one single line you can use this:

```
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But this could have negative influence when your text is shown on a mobile-phone - the line of text might get too wide..

You can insert the line of text in a span to avoid 'white-span' on all paragraphs:

```
<p>This is some random text that I am <span style="white-space:nowrap">typing on the screen for an example.</span></p>
<p>My second line for this example</p>
```

Comment: This could also have a negative influence on the webpage if you're not wanting all paragraph elements to be non-wrapped.

Comment: you are right - in that case use a span inline-styling for that line of text